# Hosts file ignored Mac 10.11.4 El Capitan

Tags: macos, hosts

I am running a RoR app on my local. I have some translations in my hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   example.dev
127.0.0.1   www.example.dev
127.0.0.1   api.example.dev
```

They were working fine, until I updated my OS to 10.11.4. If I send `ping` request to `www.example.dev`, it seems to work fine. The IP it translates to is `127.0.0.1`.

But when I visit `www.example.dev` in my web browser, it seems to ignore hosts file and ping DNS server for IP.

I am not sure how, but going to `localhost` in browser does translate to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: What is `RoR` please?

Comment: Sorry @MarkSetchell its Ruby on Rails server.

Comment: Same issue here.. I just bought my mac air and customisation on the host file seems ignored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dont know why but ive disabled my lookback adapter and ipv6 and now its working.

so in your host file disable these two items

```
# ::1               localhost  
# fe80::1%lo0       localhost
```

Some fubar osx bug... I miss steve....

Comment: How does that disable the *loop*back interface?

Comment: This is what I tried (before your answer), and it worked for me. So marking it as the possible solution.

Comment: Wow wtf. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Interesting. It was working for me up until recently. I use the StevenBlack host files. I only had to comment out the ipv6 loopback but yeah, this definitely fixed it.

Comment: Just commenting the ::1 worked for me too... amazing

Answer (score 5):

I came across this while searching for an answer to a similar problem and wanted to post my findings for anyone else in the same position.

As a team of three, we found that edits to my /etc/hosts file appeared to work, while editing the other two's host files seemingly did not. Upon further digging, we realized I was on OS X 10.10, while they were on newer versions.

We found, after trying about a million things, that additions to the hosts file in 10.11 and up apparently could not have more than one space between the IP and the domain, for example:

DID NOT WORK:

```
1.2.3.4     some.site.com
```

DID WORK:

```
1.2.3.4 some.site.com
```

After making this change, we immediately started seeing expected results without any cache clears, reboots, or otherwise.

Comment: After an hour of debugging I removed the extra spaces and it worked.. Thanks!

Comment: For me ( In the future ) this didn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 0):

The host you are overriding is resolving via IPV6.  
  ::1 is the loopback address for IPV6 which is analogous to 127.0.0.1 in IPV4. Add the following entries as the last lines in your /etc/hosts file.

::1 localhost
::1             www.example.dev